# how to browse files correctly using FileImporter in swiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am new to swiftUI and there is few information about FIleImporter. I am currently writing a file into

```
let documentsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let notesPath  = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent("locations").appendingPathExtension("json")
```

And then on my ContentView, I have a button to browse the folder of that directory:

```
Button(action:{
                showingDirectory = true
            }){
                HStack{
                    Text("Browsed Saved Track")
                }
            }.fileImporter(isPresented: $showingDirectory, allowedContentTypes: [.json], allowsMultipleSelection: false){
                result in
            }
```

However when I run the code, the file broswer came out blank with bug info:
**[AXRuntimeCommon] Unknown client: assign4**

I had confirmed that the file does exist in:
file:///Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/.../data/Containers/Data/Application/D64B3041-7706-48C9-A6AE-9530DC074A86/Documents/locations.json

I think the potential reason is that the file browsing might need permission in info.plist, but I do not know which one, I tried
[image]

But none of these work, can someone please help me on this? Thank you!!!!

Comment: Is it macOS or iOS?

Comment: This is IOS I believe, this is a Xcode project for iphone

Comment: You ever find a solution to this?